# Can I import a parameter defined file in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

For a specific situation, my Symfony2 project has different versions of configuration files. A concrete simple example would be the security file :

```
security_db.yml
security_ldap.yml
```

I would like the used file to be defined in the `parameters.ini` file.
This is what I tried to add in the `config.yml`:

```
imports:
- { resource: "security_%authentification%.yml" }
```

While having the `authentification` parameter defined in my `parameters.ini` file but I always have the same error :

```
The file "security_%authentification%.yml" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe one way to do this is to use your Extension class to load the proper config based on what is defined in your parameters.ini ... This is untested ...

**src/MyAwesomeBundle/DependencyInjection/MyAwesomeExtension.php**

```php
class MyAwesomeExtension extends Extension 
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
       // boiler plate code here ... this probably already exists in your class.
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        // your personalized loader goes here ...
        $myloader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

        $auth = $container->getParameter('authentication');
        if (isset($auth)) {
            $myloader->load('security_' . $auth . '.yml');
        }
    }

}
```